# D3 Treemap reset color

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently working on a software visualization tool that uses treemaps.

IMG: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7s5np5x7or94tky/Screenshot%202014-03-25%2010.31.51.png

In my tool you are allowed to search elements that will then be highlighted in the treemap accordingly to the color you have chosen. Now I need to revert the colors of the elements as they were before I highlighted them.

Is there any way to fully re-render the treemap or even better a way to revert a single element (e.g. `d3.select("#e-123").resetColor()`)?

Comment: how about select element via jQuery or via native functionality like document.querySelectorAll and then do what you want

Comment: @DnisterLark I can already select the element via `d3.select("#e-123")` but then the problem is how to revert the color the the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no functionality in D3 to "reset" an attribute value. Here are two options.

#### Assign a CSS class for the highlighting

The code for highlighting would then be something like

```
d3.select("foo").classed("highlight", true);
```

and to reset

```
d3.select("foo").classed("highlight", false);
```

#### Store the old attribute value with the data when setting it

To set the highlight, the code would look something like

```
d3.select("foo").attr("color", function(d) {
  d.oldColor = d3.select(this).attr("color");
  return newColor;
});
```

then to reset

```
d3.select("foo").attr("color", function(d) { return d.oldColor; });
```

The first approach is less code, but if you have a large number of different colors, the second method may be more convenient.